# Running a Moderated Mediation analysis with Ordinal ModV in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have data collected from a survey that i want to build a moderated mediation model with. My four variables are:

- `Bullying` = Continuous, average response to several Likert Scale Questions from an individual, range 1-5 (IV)
- `Self-Esteem` = Continuous, calculated as above (Mediator)
- `Dissatisfaction` = Continuous, calculated as above (DV)
- `Year Level` = Discrete Ordinal, range from 1-10 (Moderator)

I have already calculated and found that `Self-Esteem` is a simple Mediator of the effect `Bullying -> Dissatisfaction`. I now want to see if `Year level` is a Moderator of this Mediation model, however the only guides I can find rely on splitting the Moderator into two dichotomous groups, which I don't want to do. I think I have found that `Year Level` is not a simple moderator for the `Bullying -> Dissatisfaction` effect through the code:

```
Bullying_c <- c(scale(Bullying, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE))
SelfEsteem_c <- c(scale(SelfEsteem, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE))

fitMod <- lm(Dissatisfaction ~ Bullying_c + SelfEsteem_c + Bullying_c*SelfEsteem_c)
fitModB <- Boot(fitMod, R = 1000)
summary (fitModB)
```

Which outputs:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5143 -0.6560 -0.2014  0.5426  3.0809 

Coefficients: 
                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)              1.853848   0.032137  57.686  < 2e-16 ***
Bullying_c               0.203157   0.027922   7.276  8.5e-13 ***
SelfEsteem_c             -0.036391   0.015824  -2.300   0.0217 *  
Bullying_c:SelfEsteem_c   0.007795   0.012430   0.627   0.5308
```

Which shows that `Self-esteem` is not an overall moderator, hence I'm looking at Moderated Mediation, not Mediated Moderation.

I've tried looking up the packages: `psych` , `mediation`, and `lavaan`, but I've been unable to find a way to run the analysis with an ordinal Moderator. Most guides want me to choose two values of the moderator, but I want to include all 10 classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through continued research I stumbled across the `rosetta` package, which contains the function `gemm()`, which can create this model with the following code:

```
result <- gemm(data = mydata,
xvar = "Bullying_c",
mvar = "SelfEsteem_c",
yvar = "Dissatisfaction",
xmmod = "YearLevel",
nboot = 5000)

print(result)
```

This function also allows for covariates. The `gemm()` function is clearly explained on the following pages:

Details about the function:
https://rdrr.io/github/psytext/rosetta/man/gemm.html

Link to PDF download for a tutorial running these analysis and interpreting results:
https://psyarxiv.com/mj2ug/download